# Pass client-side javascript variable to server-side php

Tags: php, javascript, prototypejs

I try again to ask my question. I hope that this time it's clear enough.

Here's the live demo of my script:
http://www.virusgaming.net/test/

And this is the code:

```
<? // I set the starting percentage to 0%. 
$something = 0; ?>      

<!-- jsProgressBarHandler prerequisites : prototype.js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype/prototype.js"></script>

<!-- jsProgressBarHandler core -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bramus/jsProgressBarHandler.js"></script>        

<span style="color:#006600;font-weight:bold;">Multi Color Bar</span> <br/>
<span id="element6">Loading...</span>
<span class="extra"><a href="#" onclick="manualPB2.setPercentage('0', true);return false;"><img src="images/icons/empty.gif" alt="" title="" onmouseout="$('Text6').innerHTML ='&laquo; Select Options'" onmouseover="$('Text6').innerHTML ='Empty Bar'"/></a></span>
<span class="options"><a href="#" onclick="manualPB2.setPercentage('+10');return false;"><img src="images/icons/add.gif" alt="" title="" onmouseout="$('Text6').innerHTML ='&laquo; Select Options'" onmouseover="$('Text6').innerHTML ='Add 10%'"/></a></span>
<span class="options"><a href="#" onclick="manualPB2.setPercentage('-5');return false;"><img src="images/icons/minus.gif" alt="" title="" onmouseout="$('Text6').innerHTML ='&laquo; Select Options'" onmouseover="$('Text6').innerHTML ='Minus 5%'" /></a></span>
<span class="options"><a href="#" onclick="manualPB2.setPercentage('30');return false;"><img src="images/icons/set.gif" alt="" title="" onmouseout="$('Text6').innerHTML ='&laquo; Select Options'" onmouseover="$('Text6').innerHTML ='Set 30%'"/></a></span>
<span class="options"><a href="#" onclick="manualPB2.setPercentage('98'); manualPB2.setPercentage('30'); return false;"><img src="images/icons/fill.gif" alt="" title="" onmouseout="$('Text6').innerHTML ='&laquo; Select Options'" onmouseover="$('Text6').innerHTML ='Fill 98%, and then 30%'" /></a></span>
<span class="getOption"><a href="#" onclick="alert(manualPB2.getPercentage());return false;"><img src="images/icons/get.gif" alt="" title="" onmouseout="$('Text6').innerHTML ='&laquo; Select Options'" onmouseover="$('Text6').innerHTML ='Get Current %'"/></a></span>
<span id="Text6" style="font-weight:bold">&laquo; Select Options</span>

<script type="text/javascript">                     
    document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {

        manualPB2 = new JS_BRAMUS.jsProgressBar(
                    $('element6'),
                    <? echo $something; ?>,                             
                    {

                        barImage    : Array(
                            'images/bramus/percentImage_back4.png',
                            'images/bramus/percentImage_back3.png',
                            'images/bramus/percentImage_back2.png',
                            'images/bramus/percentImage_back1.png'
                        ),

                        onTick : function(pbObj) {

                            switch(pbObj.getPercentage()) {

                                case 70:
                                    alert('we are at 70%');
                                break;

                                case 100:
                                    alert('we are at 100%');                                        
                                break;                                                                                                                                                                              

                            }

                            return true; 
                        }
                    }
                );
    }, false);
</script>
```

I want to pass the client-side javascript percentage to server-side php variable. I did tens of tries with GET and POST javascript (hidden fields, forms, anchor, onclick event etc) with no success. Basically with the **onclick="alert(manualPB2.getPercentage());** function i stamp the current percentage in an alert. Is possible edit this alert so that it post/get the variable to php?

Comment: In short -> Create hidden form with hidden input field... assign this value to that input's value and then submit that form. Or just use Ajax.

Comment: Sure.  Use ajax (prototype should have plenty of documentation about how to accomplish what you want if you start with that).  What are you trying to track the progress of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the alert, try this ajax call,

```
 var url = 'YourServerSideScript.php';
 var pars = 'percentage=' + pbObj.getPercentage(); // you have to use $_POST['percentage'] on your script
 var target = 'targeDivId';
 var myAjax = new Ajax.Updater(target, url, {method: 'post', parameters: pars});
```

Comment: Thank you for you code but i can only get "undefined" as result. I've tryed for 2 hours to get the point with no success. Why?

Answer (score 0):

As a variation on jose's answer (there's no need to use `Ajax.Updater` unless you're expecting an HTML response) Prototype really does provide everything you need.

```
document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
    // after existing initialising code...

    $$('.getOption a').first().observe('click', function(event) {
        new Ajax.Request('YourServerSideScript.php', {
            parameters: {
                percentage: parseInt(manualPB2.getPercentage())
            }
        });
        event.stop();
    });
});
```

...and the value will be `$_POST['percentage']` in your script. I didn't set `method` since it will be POST anyway, and `parameters` is an object which means Prototype will urlencode it for you, so saving the effort. Remember to read the [manual](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/).

`parseInt` will strip out any `%` characters if they exist in the percentage. [`event.stop()`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Event/prototype/stop/) neatly prevents the anchor's normal click behaviour.